# Fetch all names into multi row block

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have tables that looks like this:

```
tbl1
+---------+
|c_no     |
+---------+
|1        |
+---------+

tbl2
+----------+---------+
|tbl1_c_no |s_name   |
+----------+---------+
|1         |A        |
|1         |D        |
+----------+---------+
```

My form:

[image]

◘ The 1st block's base table usage is tbl1.
◘ C_NO field is auto generated using sequence. (required).
◘ S_GR is just an unbound item. (not required).
◘ The 2nd block's base table usage is tbl2 and is multiple row.
◘ S_NAME. (required)
◘ 1st block is like the parent of 2nd block.
◘ 1st and 2nd block is linked using c_no and tbl1_c_no

For example if I wanted to add some data, it's like this:

[image]

Then press F10 for saving:

[image]

```
tbl1 will be:
+---------+
|c_no     |
+---------+
|1        |
|2        |
+---------+

tbl2 will be:
+----------+---------+
|tbl1_c_no |s_name   |
+----------+---------+
|1         |A        |
|1         |D        |
|2         |B        |
|2         |C        |
|2         |E        |
+----------+---------+
```

And my problem is that I wanted to fetch s_names from my 3rd table into 2nd block.

```
tbl3
+----------+---------+
|s_gr      |s_name   |
+----------+---------+
|80        |F        |
|85        |G        |
|84        |H        |
|84        |I        |
|80        |J        |
+----------+---------+
```

Like this:

[image]

then after leaving S_GR field, it will fetch S_NAME from tbl3 that S_GR = 80 into the 2nd block

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two blocks :

- for the **1st** one, to have a block with **no base table**, create manually just by touching `Data Blocks` node
  with mouse's cursor and then toggling the create icon (*a green plus
  sign* ) and type a name `blk_no`. And add a field s_no on the canvas.
- for the **2nd** one use `Data Block Wizard` and choose `Table or View type`
  for the type of the block. There select the table(**tbl1**)'s both columns
  (`s_no` and `name`) as `Database Items`.

  And then, the forms must invoke
  `Layout Wizard` automatically as default, where choose only `name` column
  as ***displayed*** and leave `s_no` hidden as to be . Name the block as `blk_names`. This is a **base-table** block, and `Data Source Name` of the block `blk_names` is *the table **tbl1***.

  By the way, set `Number of Records Displayed` property to `10` as an example, and convert the name of the field `name` to `snames` as in your question.

  Set block's ***WHERE Clause*** (in ***Database*** node) as  `s_no = :blk_no.s_no` at the Property Palette. After
  all, create a `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` trigger on `s_no` field with the inline
  code :

  ```
  go_block('blk_names');
  execute_query;
  ```

At the runtime you can enter an integer value( *let's give `1` as an example* ) for `s_no` and populate the `names` field by pressing `enter key` ( *the records with `A` and `D` will appear* )

A button might be added with `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger having the code :

```
 go_block('blk_names');
 delete tbl2;
 first_record;
while :blk_names.s_no is not null 
loop
 insert into tbl2 values(:snames);
 next_record;
end loop;   
 commit;
```

*to populate and re-populate the table **tbl2***( in this case **tbl2** is populated with the records `A` and `D`  ).

P.S. To suppress the message

> ***FRM-40352***: Last Record of Query retrieved

add an `ON-MESSAGE` trigger at the forms level wtih the code :

```
if message_code = 40352 then 
    null;
end if;
```

Comment: I am very sorry sir. I forgot to mention something important in my question yesterday. I already edited it. Thanks.

Comment: sir I don't have s_no field for my 2nd table.

Comment: sir sorry for disturbing you and taking your time. I need to do it by creating 2 different blocks. one for just entering s_no that is not having a base table usage and another one that uses tbl2 as base table usage.

Comment: I need to display the names first after entering s_no then save names on tbl2

Comment: @Miracle no, not problem. Consider applying the new answer.

Comment: Sir I made my question clearer because of your answer. I edited it again. Please don't get mad at me this is the last time I'll edit this. Thank you

Comment: @Miracle no :) but I need to work harder for this daunting job.